# How Can I Access A Broken Ubuntu 14.04 File System?

Tags: 14.04, mount, files, directory, aws

Configuration:
AWS t2.micro instance (name:webserver) set up with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS; this instance is stopped and the EBS volume (name:broken) containing the instance (name:webserver) has been mounted at `/mnt` on a second AWS t2.micro instance (name:recovery) running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (the same OS as the stopped instance).

Question:  How do I access the Ubuntu file system in the mounted EBS volume (name:broken)?  The directories and files I'm looking for are per this list, taken from the server (name:recovery).

```
total 84
drwxr-xr-x  22 root root  4096 Jul 27 05:35 .
drwxr-xr-x  22 root root  4096 Jul 27 05:35 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Mar 25 11:52 bin
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Mar 25 11:52 boot
drwxr-xr-x  13 root root  4020 Jul 25 16:53 dev
drwxr-xr-x  89 root root  4096 Jul 25 21:37 etc
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Jul 25 15:46 home
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    33 Mar 25 11:51 initrd.img -> boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-48-generic
drwxr-xr-x  21 root root  4096 Mar 25 11:51 lib
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Mar 25 11:50 lib64
drwx------   2 root root 16384 Mar 25 11:53 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Mar 25 11:50 media
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Mar 25 11:50 opt
dr-xr-xr-x 109 root root     0 Jul 25 15:46 proc
drwx------   3 root root  4096 Jul 25 15:46 root
drwxr-xr-x  18 root root   660 Jul 26 06:27 run
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Mar 25 11:52 sbin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Mar 25 11:50 srv
drwxrwx---  13 root root     0 Jul 26 14:17 sys
```

The same directories and files should be somewhere in the mounted volume (name:broken), but I've not been able to find them.

Comment / status:  When I use `ls -al /mnt` -- I get a very nice listing of the virtual machine's directories and files, per the following.

```
total 4
drwxrwx--- 13 root root    0 Jul 26 14:17 .
drwxr-xr-x 22 root root 4096 Jul 27 05:35 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    0 Jul 25 15:46 block
drwxr-xr-x 28 root root    0 Jul 25 15:46 bus
drwxr-xr-x 46 root root    0 Jul 25 15:46 class
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root    0 Jul 25 15:46 dev
drwxr-xr-x 16 root root    0 Jul 25 15:46 devices
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root    0 Jul 25 15:46 firmware
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root    0 Jul 25 15:46 fs
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root    0 Jul 25 21:38 hypervisor
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root    0 Jul 25 15:46 kernel
drwxr-xr-x 92 root root    0 Jul 25 15:46 module
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    0 Jul 25 21:38 power
```

These directories and files are the structure of the virtual machine that runs Ubuntu 14.04.  So far as I can tell, there is nothing in this file structure related to the Ubuntu file system itself. I've done a full tree listing of `/mnt`, and searched it for the Ubuntu system directories and files -- without success.

My objective in pursuing this topic is to get access to a broken configuration file in the image (name:webserver) to repair it, and (hopefully) recover the image so it is again usable.

I've reviewed the AWS documentation and the Ubuntu man pages for directories and files, and for access to them.  I've also searched in AskUbuntu and StackOverflow (and other forums).  So far I've not been able to suss out the answer, so am turning to the experts at AskUbuntu for assistance.  TIA for an answer.

Comment: What are "user level files"? ` /bin`, `/boot`, `/dev`,` /etc` etc., should be inaccessible to regular users. Why would they contain any user files? Please [edit] your question and show us the files you see when running `ls -al /mnt` (use the [formatting tools](http://askubuntu.com/help/formatting) to make them display correctly). Also, please clarify exactly what files you are looking for.

Comment: @terdon -- thank you for your comment, it has helped me to revise the question, and hopefully, to improve it.

Answer (score 1):

OK, thanks to several folks on this and other forums, I found the answer.  The key is to know the file system type of the partition of interest.  The `lsblk` command shows where the (name:broken) volume is mounted.  The `mount` command with no parameters provides the required information about file system type, which is ext4 in this case.  Note that several other file system types also have data in them, but it is not the data needed to fix the problem.

```
$ lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0   8G  0 disk
└─xvda1 202:1    0   8G  0 part /
xvdf    202:80   0  24G  0 disk
└─xvdf1 202:81   0  24G  0 part

$ mount
/dev/xvda1 on / type ext4 (rw,discard)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
none on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw)
systemd on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,none,name=systemd)
```

Now that this is known, make the mount point directory:

```
$ mkdir ./mnt
```

... mount the volume:

```
$ sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/xvdf1 ./mnt
```

... check to see that the right directories and files are available:

```
$ ls -al ./mnt
total 100
drwxr-xr-x 22 root   root    4096 Jul 25 14:32 .
drwxr-xr-x  6 ubuntu ubuntu  4096 Jul 29 07:20 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root    4096 Mar 25 11:52 bin
drwxr-xr-x  3 root   root    4096 Mar 25 11:52 boot
drwxr-xr-x  5 root   root    4096 Mar 25 11:53 dev
drwxr-xr-x 89 root   root    4096 Jul 29 06:46 etc
drwxr-xr-x  4 root   root    4096 Jul 23 02:21 home
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root      33 Mar 25 11:51 initrd.img -> boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-48-generic
drwxr-xr-x 21 root   root    4096 Mar 25 11:51 lib
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root    4096 Mar 25 11:50 lib64
drwx------  2 root   root   16384 Mar 25 11:53 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root    4096 Mar 25 11:50 media
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root    4096 Apr 10  2014 mnt
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root    4096 Mar 25 11:50 opt
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root    4096 Apr 10  2014 proc
drwx------  3 root   root    4096 Jul 22 04:40 root
drwxr-xr-x  3 root   root    4096 Mar 25 11:53 run
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root    4096 Mar 25 11:52 sbin
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root    4096 Mar 25 11:50 srv
drwxr-xr-x  2 root   root    4096 Mar 13  2014 sys
drwxrwxrwt  2 root   root    4096 Jul 29 06:52 tmp
drwxr-xr-x 10 root   root    4096 Mar 25 11:50 usr
drwxr-xr-x 12 root   root    4096 Mar 25 11:52 var
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root      30 Mar 25 11:51 vmlinuz -> boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-48-generic
```

... they are, so now it is time to edit the broken file:

```
$ sudo nano ./mnt/etc/sudoers
```

Yes, found the bad line, fixed it, and wrote out the corrected file.

Next steps:

1. unmount the recovered volume,
2. stop the recovery instance,
3. detach the recovered volume from the recovery instance,
4. attach the recovered volume to the original instance (be sure to specify the block device name as `/dev/sda1` -- use anything else then IT DOES NOT WORK),
5. restart the original instance, and confirm that it functions properly.

I mis-keyed the required entry, `/dev/sda1` (tried `/dev/sda`, `/dev/xvda`, etc. -- no go) and didn't find it for a while.  So, while the volume did re-attach, it wasn't recognized as the boot volume.  Once I entered /dev/sda1 as the block device name, it was accepted, recognized as the boot volume, and everything *just worked*.  SO GLAD THIS IS DONE!  It has been a real learning experience.  I hope this helps someone else who runs into these types of issues.